# MongoDB add serial number to each document using MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

Here is some info about my db :

```
collection name: questions
db name: school
```

This is the structure of my document :

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("630680a764a8eb1364c4f250"),
    question_type: 'MULTIPLE CHOICE',
    published: true,
    status: 'PUBLISHED',
}
```

Here I wants to add serial number to each document like auto increment number.
`_id` will be there I want serial number to add each document with one query.

Please take a look how can I do this .

Answer (score 3):

Since mongoDB 5.0, one option is to use `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {_id: 1},
      output: {
        serial: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gB-dc-DJ20d)